# How can i put TextField in AlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITextField in UIAlertView on iPhone - how to make it responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376104/uitextfield-in-uialertview-on-iphone-how-to-make-it-responsive)
>   [UITextField in UIAlertView alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762359/uitextfield-in-uialertview-alternative)

i want to put TextField in AlertView when the alert is displayed to the users.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376104/uitextfield-in-uialertview-on-iphone-how-to-make-it-responsive check this

Comment: Please search before asking a question! this question asked many times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since iOS5 you can use UIAlertViewStyle to add the different Textinput into the UIAlertview

[Example Link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

from [UITextField in UIAlertView on iPhone - how to make it responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376104/uitextfield-in-uialertview-on-iphone-how-to-make-it-responsive)

```
UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[dialog setDelegate:self];
[dialog setTitle:@"Enter Name"];
[dialog setMessage:@" "];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
[nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[dialog addSubview:nameField];
CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 100.0);
[dialog setTransform: moveUp];
[dialog show];
[dialog release];
[nameField release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it as a `subView` to the `UIAlertView` object with the frame size that you desire !

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, its a little long, but I set it and forgot and it works...

```
alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:t message:@"" delegate:self     cancelButtonTitle:@"CANCEL" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

pinField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 38, 244, 31)];
pinField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[alertView show];


[alertView insertSubview:pinField atIndex:2];


NSArray * subviews = [alertView subviews];
UILabel * label1 = [subviews objectAtIndex:1];
UIImageView * bg = [subviews objectAtIndex:0];
UIView * button1 = [subviews objectAtIndex:4];
UIView * button2 = [subviews objectAtIndex:5];
float height = 0;
height = 16 + label1.frame.size.height;
CGRect frame = label1.frame;
frame.origin.y = 8;
label1.frame = frame;

frame = pinField.frame;
frame.origin.y = height;
pinField.frame = frame;

height += 8 + frame.size.height;
frame = button1.frame;
frame.origin.y = height;
button1.frame = frame;

frame = button2.frame;
frame.origin.y = height;
button2.frame = frame;

height += 8 + frame.size.height;
frame = alertView.frame;
frame.size.height = height +8;
alertView.frame= frame;

frame = bg.frame;
frame.size.height = alertView.frame.size.height;
bg.frame = frame;

[pinField release];
[alertView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class which inherits from UIAlertview and add a textfield element to it.

Then write this method :

```
-(id)init
{
    txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero]; // your frame here
    [self addSubview: txtField];

    return self;
}
```

This might help.
Now create an object of this class in some other class and test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save As" message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
self.textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[self.textfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[myAlertView addSubview:self.textfield];
[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *customAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your title here!" message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];

[txtField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[customAlertView addSubview:txtField];

[customAlertView show];

[customAlertView release];
```